# XSLT / xsltproc - don't change order of attributes

Tags: xml, xslt

I want to transform an XML document into an XML documents with XSLT. Some nodes are formatted like this:

```
<node attrZ="..."
      attrB="Hello 'FooBar'"
      xmlns="..."/>
```

After the transform process with *xsltproc* it looks like:

```
<node xmlns="..." attrB="Hello &apos;FooBar&apos;" attrZ="..."/>
```

This happened with all nodes:

```
<xsl:output method="xml" version='1.0' indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="node() | @*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node() |@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

It is possible suppress reformating of attributes (order, newline, ...), escaping of characters in attributes aor change indent of "untouch"/copied nodes?

Thank you

Andreas

Comment: Attributes are essentially unordered in the XSLT data model and any whitespace in between attributes is not stored and can't therefore not be preserved.  Furthermore any node is parsed and serialized back with your identity transformation and serializing `'` as `&apos;` is not changing the attribute value at all.

Comment: Reordering of the `xmlns` attribute to number one position is normal behavior.  All XSLT processors seem to do it.

Comment: @MartinHonnen  Thank you for your answer. The answer I feared. The XML files are stored in a repository and should be changed as little as possible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is no. The XSLT processor has no idea what order the attributes originally appeared in (the XML parser doesn't supply this information), so it has no prospect of retaining this order.

The escaping of apostrophes here is a little clumsy (because it's not necessary) and a different XSLT processor might be smarter about it; similarly other processors might be smarter in their indentation algorithms, but basically this is something over which you have no control - and it shouldn't matter.

Comment: I actually think it does matter when having many attributes within finance report data. Having the attributes sorted in a controlled way, simplifies the troubleshooting and readability of the output code (XHTML). The sorting does not matter for the system, but it would be a great benefit for the system developer and admin user.

Comment: Indeed, it does help the human reader, which is why I added an option to the Saxon processor to control the output order of attributes on serialization. Sadly it also matters when the XML is being read by incompetently written Perl scripts that try to parse XML using regular expressions.